# Unable to click on a button placed inside an iframe in Safari browser with Selenium

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver

OS: OSX macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Selenium Version: 3.6.0

Browser: Safari

Browser Version: 11.0.1(12604.3.2)

Expected Behavior - click() action should work on a button located inside an iframe in Safari browser

Actual Behavior - No action when performed button.click() action on Safari browser

Steps to reproduce -

1. Open safari browser
2. Access web application login screen
3. Enter valid credentials and click on Login button, pop up appears
4. Switch to iframe
5. Click on button placed inside an iframe

No action when clicked on button. Same code is working fine in other browsers(Chrome, Mozilla, IE11)

Below is the code:

```
SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
options.setUseCleanSession(true);
driver = new SafariDriver(options); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("testurl");
driver.findElement(By.id("UN")).sendKeys("admin");
driver.findElement(By.id("UN")).sendKeys("admin$");
driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'dijitDialog') and contains(@style,'z-index: 950;')]//*[starts-with(@id,'AxDojo_Dialog_frame')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ButtonPlaceHolder']/button[2]")).click();
```

No action when last step is executed.
As work around found an alternate to perform click on the button with below code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ButtonPlaceHolder']/button[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

But like this we need to change in many areas, Selenium is browser independent and maintenance of code browser wise is tedious task to us. Please can anyone look into this issue.

Please find HTML code inside iframe.

```
<iframe id="AxDojo_Dialog_frame_1508320744505" name="AxDojo_Dialog_frame_1508320744505" style="border: 0px; width: 605px; height: 159px;" width="605" height="136px" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="about:blank" axpageload="1"></iframe>
#document
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow-y: hidden"><head>
<title>Login</title>
<link href="../AxCommon/Styles/ECDefault/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../Packages/Scripts/JQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../AxCommon/Scripts/AxSystemBroadcast.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../AxCommon/Scripts/AxMyParent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/AxDialog.js?v=14082015"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .DialogBtn{width: 80px; font-size: 10pt;white-space:nowrap;}
    .DialogCustomBtn{font-size: 10pt;white-space:nowrap;}
    #popupMandatoryDiv { display:none;position:relative;height:auto;background:#FFFFFF;z-index:999999;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black;padding:5px 20px 10px 18px;font-size:12px;}
    li {list-style: none; }
    /*li:before {content:'\2022'; display: block; position: relative; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; left: -13px; top: -4px; color: red; font-size: 20px;padding-right: 5px;}*/
    li:before {content:'\2217'; display: block; position: relative; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; left: -13px; top: -2px; color: red;font-weight:bold}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divMask" style="height: auto; width: auto;">
        <table id="Table1" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td rowspan="3" style="width: 3px; height: 5px" valign="top" align="center"></td>
                <td colspan="2" valign="top" align="center" height="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:100%">
                <td valign="top" align="center" width="10%">
                    <img id="IconImage" src="../AxCommon/Images/28 information.gif">
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" align="left" height="5" width="90%">
                    <div id="divPrompt" align="left" style="DISPLAY: block; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; DIRECTION: ltr;">You are already logged into Excelicare in other active session(s). Please choose one of the options below:</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 100%; display: none;">
                <td valign="top" align="center" width="10%">
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="left" height="5" width="90%">
                    <div id="popupMandatoryDiv" align="left" style="DISPLAY: block; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; OVERFLOW: auto; DIRECTION: ltr;display:none">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px">
                    <div id="ButtonPlaceHolder"><button class="DialogCustomBtn" onclick="AxSysF_CloseWindow(6)">Open new session / <br>end other session(s)</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="DialogCustomBtn" onclick="AxSysF_CloseWindow(7)">Open new session / <br>retain other session(s)</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="DialogCustomBtn" onclick="AxSysF_CloseWindow(0)">Cancel login<br>&nbsp;</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trchkPlaceHolder" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="middle" align="left" colspan="3" id="tdchkPlaceHolder">
                    <div id="checkPlaceHolder"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <div>
            <br>
            <div id="lblInfo" style="display: block;"><b>Note : </b> If you choose to <i>Open new session/end other session(s)</i> any unsaved data in the other session(s) will be lost.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="hdnTitle" type="hidden" value="Login">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var strProductType = '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ProductType")%>';
    strModulePageName = 'frmdialog';
    $(document).ready(function() { PageLoaded();setTimeout('self.focus()', 10);});
    function setCallback(CallbackFn) {
        _CallbackFn = CallbackFn;
    }
    document.oncontextmenu = function (event) {return false;};  
</script>

</body></html>
```

[image: Picture2]

[image: JavaScript Console when application opened in Safari Private mode]

Comment: Can you expand the `HTML DOM` of the `<button>` tag of our interest (possibly all of them) and paste the formatted `HTML DOM` within your question area for further analysis. I suppose the the `<button>` tag does contains a `<span>` tag within which may help us further.

Comment: I guess it is about security policy of Safari private mode. Can you open your website in Safari private mode and take a look at Develop > JavaScript Console? Is there any errors?

Comment: @DebanjanB  I've added HTML code snippet in my question and also shared another screenshot expanding  <button> tag. Please find the details.

Comment: @Buaban Thanks for the response, I've manually accessed application and performed click on login screen and observed some errors in JavaScript Console. Added screenshot to my question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot/HTML you provided, there needs some modification in your code block as follows:

1. The line :

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'dijitDialog') and contains(@style,'z-index: 950;')]//*[starts-with(@id,'AxDojo_Dialog_frame')]")));
   ```

Though the outer HTML element does have the `class` attribute as `dijitDialogPaneContent` but doesn't have `style` attribute as `z-index: 950;`.

2. The line :

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ButtonPlaceHolder']/button[2]")).click();
   ```

As you are using `xpath` with index e.g. `button[2]` the `xpath` becomes brittle and vulnarable. I would have prefered to expand the `<button>` tag and use the `<span>` or any other tag/text present within to construct an unique `css`/`xpath`.

3. Following those 2 observation you can make some minor changes in your code as follows:

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitDialogPaneContent')/iframe[starts-with(@id, 'AxDojo_Dialog_frame')]")));
   //clicking the first button
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='DialogCustomBtn' and contains(.,'end other session(s)')]")).click();
   ```

> In-case the loading sequence of this `<iframe>` is constant, our `xpath` would be much more generic as follows:

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitDialogPaneContent')//following::iframe[1]")));
    //clicking the first button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='DialogCustomBtn' and contains(.,'end other session(s)')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions given by you. I tried both the solutions given by you, but no luck, click is not working. Its working when used sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)